Why is there a difference in autofocus in vuetify 2 and vuetify 3?
I have a problem that needs explaining regarding the difference in autofocus in Vuetify 2 and Vuetify 3. Does anyone know why there is a difference ?
Thank you !
Click to see image of autofocus difference between vuetify 2 and vuetify 3
I tried checking the issue of vuetify 3 but didn't see it.
If there is any document related to this issue, please let me know.

Vuetify 3's behavior is in line with the HTML spec. Only one element can have autofocus.
